# How to add values from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> to Edit Text

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I want to add my values to edit text which I stored in my Array list here is the code please help me out. The values not set in Edit Text.

```
public class AgentProfile extends Activity {

EditText edtname,edtaddress,edtmobile,edtfather;
Button bback;
private SimpleAdapter adapter;
static final String KEY_TABLE = "AGENTPROFILE";
static final String KEY_NAME = "AGENTNAME";// parent node
static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "ADDRESS";// parent node
static final String KEY_COUNTRY= "COUNTRY";
static final String KEY_MOBILE = "MOBNO1";
static final String KEY_FATHER= "FATHERNAME";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agent_profile);

    edtname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
    edtaddress= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtaddress);
    edtmobile= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtmobile);
    edtfather= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtfather);
    bback= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnback);
    select s=new select();
    s.execute("");
    bback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(AgentProfile.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });

}

public class select extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


        WebServiceCall com = new WebServiceCall();

        Intent intent =getIntent();
        Bundle b =intent.getExtras();
        final String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Agentid");

        // messageBox("test", Agentid);

        String  strXml=com.BP("AgentProfile",string1);

        //messageBox("test", strXml);
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(strXml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TABLE);
        //String[] arList = null;
        //String[] arListkey = null;
        //  int conttotal=0;
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
        {

            // creating new HashMap
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_ADDRESS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ADDRESS));
            map.put(KEY_COUNTRY, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COUNTRY));
            map.put(KEY_MOBILE, parser.getValue(e,KEY_MOBILE));

            map.put(KEY_FATHER, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FATHER));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        return strXml;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        edtmobile.setText(KEY_MOBILE);
        edtfather.setText(KEY_FATHER);
    }
}


private boolean connectionAvailable() {
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_SUPL).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //we are connected to a network
        connected = true;
    }
    return connected;
}}
```

here is the code please help me out to store values in Edit text.

Comment: Do you use the map anywhere else? If not, why don't you just put the desired fields right into the `EditText` components?

Comment: What's the problem, **exactly**? Do you get an Exception at some point? If so, what's the error and what's the line? Or are you stuck and don't know how to continue? If so, where are you blocked, what did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: I used map for getting values from web services and after that if values are in map then I want to stor these values in edit text but it didn't stor values it just put the name of column

Answer (score 1):

```
edtmobile.setText(map.get(KEY_MOBILE));
edtfather.setText(map.get(KEY_FATHER));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to post the results of your network call back to the UI, use the onPostExecute() method, since it runs on the UI thread.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    //Get the results of the network call
    map = menuItems.get(0);
    edtname.setText(map.getValue(KEY_NAME));
    edtaddress.setText(map.getValue(KEY_ADDRESS));
    edtmobile.setText(map.getValue(KEY_MOBILE));
    edtfather.setText(map.getValue(KEY_FATHER));
}
```